# Implicit conversion from varchar to varbinary error on trying to insert byte array to database

Tags: c#, sql-server, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I want to save File into my database, so I parse it into byte[]:

```
byte[] f = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Path\To\My\File\MyFile.foo");
```

Class to create table:

```
public class Files
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public byte[] File { get; set; }
}
```

Next, in my service I want to insert my file into db:

```
db.Insert(new Files() { File = f }); // db is object to database
```

after this I get error on site:

```
Implicit conversion from data type varchar(max) to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.
```

I have no idea how to change it. I have tried to save File by MemoryStream, FileStream, saving byte per byte into new byte array and I always get this error.

Does anybody know, how to fix it?

P.S. I want ot save files into DB not only URL to files, so I need to save byte[].
P.S.2 Inserting other types into database work

thanks for any advice :)

SOLVED:

I have solved it:

If you want to put blob into database use:

```
IDbCommand cmd = db.CreateInsertStatement(new Files() { File = f });
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

And everything will work perfect!

Ofcourse if anyone know how to put Blob to DB with "Insert" method - write it. I still don't know the correct answer.

Comment: If you have answered the question, create an answer and then click "Mark as Answer" :-)

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same issue. Your solution works, but it's more of a work around. I submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/pull/144) to ServiceStack.OrmLite to fix the problem for SQL Server.